# Mumps date issue

Tags: mumps

My database reverted to June 6th, 1841 this weekend. It seems all was fine with dates on 06-05-2020.  How can I reset the date to reflect the current date?  It has always been the date in mumps was tied the computer clock/calendar; however the current date has no effect on the system date within mumps. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this should answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?hl=en#!topic/comp.lang.mumps/VawXq_XNTB8) you, what's happened